# How do I swap cases in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, case-sensitive

Is there a way to swap cases in Notepad++, so in a set of text which I select, the uppercase letters are converted to lowercase, and the lower case letters are converted to uppercase.

**Why?**

I have hundreds of subtitle files, which I spent a few hours downloading for somebody who is deaf, and needs them. However, all the subtitles have the cases the wrong way round.

This is what I am talking about:

[image]

It is really annoying. This carries on through the entire thing, and it would take years to rewrite, or right click and swap the case.

Comment: Are you open to running it through a python script/do you have python installed?

Comment: I have a funny feeling this question may be better off on SuperUser...

Comment: @JohnDorian. Yes. I have a play about with Python occasionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's what you need to do. First of all make a folder containing all of these subtitle files. For example let's call it "subtitle", also make a copy "subtitle_backup" (just in case).

Now let's say your subtitle folder is inside My Documents, create a file called correct.py in My Documents, or whichever directory also contains your subtitle directory. Do not put correct.py inside "subtitle", it should go in the directory directly above.

Copy and paste this code into correct.py

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import sys

dirpath = sys.argv[1]
onlyfiles = [ join(dirpath,f) for f in listdir(dirpath) if isfile(join(dirpath,f)) ]

def correctFile( filePath ):
        f = open(filePath, "r")
        data = f.read()
        f.close()
        fixedF = ""
        for i in data:
                if i.lower() == i:
                        fixedF = fixedF + i.upper()
                else:
                        fixedF = fixedF + i.lower()
        return fixedF

for fi in onlyfiles:
        corrected = correctFile(fi)
        f = open(fi, "w")
        f.write(corrected)
        f.close()
        print "Corrected file %s" % fi
```

Now open the command prompt, go to the directory where your correct.py file and your subtitle folder are. Run:

> python correct.py subtitle

Hope this helps, comment if you need clarification on any of the steps!

Comment: @George No problem, glad to hear it!